# Get ID for views that are added dynamically

Tags: android

How to get ID of Views that are added dynamically in layout?

```
   public class Display 
    {

        static int i;
        Dynamic_UIActivity dyn;
        private Context context;
        View mField= null;
        TextView text;
        protected int mYear;
        protected int mMonth;
        protected int mDay;
        LinearLayout ll;
        Mynewdialog dialognew;

        public Display(Context mcontext)
        {
            context=mcontext;
            ll = new LinearLayout(mcontext);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            dyn = new Dynamic_UIActivity();
       }

       public void addLabel(String text)
       {
        TextView textview = new TextView(context);
        textview.setText(text);
        ll.addView(textview);       
        }

        public void addField(String Type,String Tag)
        {
            mField.setId(i);
            i++;
            if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("text"))
           {
                mField= new EditText(context);
                mField.setTag(Tag);
                //int id = mField.getResources().getIdentifier((String) mField.getTag(),"id" ,dyn.getPackageName());
                //EditText edit = (EditText)mField.findViewById(1);
                ll.addView(mField);
            }
            if(Type.equalsIgnoreCase("datepicker"))
            {
                mField=new EditText(context);
                ((EditText) mField).setText("Pick Date");
                ll.addView(mField);
                mField.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        dialognew = new Mynewdialog(context);
                         dialognew.dialog_obj((EditText) mField);
                    }
                });
            } 
        }   

        protected DatePickerDialogWithEditText.OnDateSetListener mdatepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialogWithEditText.OnDateSetListener()
        {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view , int year , int month, int date)
             {
                  mYear = year;
                  mMonth = month;
                 mDay = date;
                 dialognew.showdialogtext();

             }
         };
     }

     class DatePickerDialogWithEditText extends DatePickerDialog 
     {
         EditText tv;    

         DatePickerDialogWithEditText(Context c, OnDateSetListener oD, int y, int m, int d, EditText tv) 
        {
             super(c, oD, y, m, d);
             this.tv = tv;
        }

         EditText getAssociatedTextView() 
         {
             return tv;
         }
    }


      class Mynewdialog 
     {
        private Context context;
        Display dis = new Display(context);
        private DatePickerDialogWithEditText dialog;

        public Mynewdialog(Context mcontext)
        {
            context=mcontext;       
        }

        public void dialog_obj(EditText editTextView)
        {
             final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             dis.mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
             dis.mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
             dis.mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
             dialog = new DatePickerDialogWithEditText(context, dis.mdatepickerdialog, dis.mYear, dis.mMonth, dis.mDay, editTextView);
            dialog.show();
        }

         public void showdialogtext()
        {
             EditText et = dialog.getAssociatedTextView();
             et.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dis.mDay).append("-").append(dis.mMonth).append("-").append(dis.mYear));
         }  
       }
```

**now I want to Set the ID of the views that I get by checking its Type?how can I do that?**

Comment: using the setid and getid mtds

Comment: but we don"t know the type of view for which we have to set Id?

Comment: now how can I get and set the ID of views that i have added at runtime??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by using getId() and setId() methods of the View.

For example:

```
TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
txtView.setId(4);
```

and you can get the ID by using getId() method:

```
txtView.getId();
```

Comment: as a sidenote, views created dynamically (through code) initially don't have an id set. You have to explicitly call setId() to give a view an Id.

Comment: @MrJre i had already mentioned it as setId(4) for the example.

Comment: @Geetanjali FYI, Id argument is of integer type.

Comment: then how can I use findviewbyid for that?

Comment: actually I have added Text View, Date Picker and Edit Text all at run time and to set their Id's first we should know what is the type of View for which we are goin to set Id?how can we do that?

Comment: @Geetanjali Why do you need to know what subclass of View a specific view is? Calling setId() on any type of View works just the same as any other.

Comment: now in this i need to get the id of the type of view that i get?how can i do this

Comment: @Geetanjali Actually you know you are in trouble of something else as you are implementing something else, without clear description, nobody is able to understand your problem exactly. so its better you raise a question with full description instead of commenting here.

Comment: @Paresh .now plz help me if u know

Comment: @Amplify91:FYI I am doing Parsing using DOM parser and for that i need to do this

Answer (score 1):

or you can add all(Dynamically created)  views in a ArrayList and then access it.