# AdMod & GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, admob

I dont know how to get this to working within my game...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setRenderer(this);
        setContentView(glView);
        int newID = glView.getId();

        // Create the adView
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e3ef0948eb58");
        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(newID);
        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);
        Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
```

This gives me a Null Pointer Exception and I cant figure out what else to do with this. Im just needing to know how to get this to work with the way I have programed this. I dont use any XML.

Also the "newID" value become -1 so thats where the error is coming from

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You don't use XML so that means your view isn't created static(in xml) but **dynamic**(in java).

Dynamically created views **don't** have a id already associated with them yet, so you must set one explicitly.

```
    view.setId(1)**//choose a non negative integer
```

Check this out: [Get ID for views that are added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746313/get-id-for-views-that-are-added-dynamically/6746386#6746386)